# Inverse of AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator on Android

Tags: android, animation, interpolation

I'm pretty much looking for exactly what the question suggests - a `DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator`. What I want to do is have an animation decelerate for the first half of the animation, and then accelerate after that. (I'm using it to mimic a gravity-like effect on a Bèzier curve).

EDIT:

Basically, what I'm looking for is something that as the object moves upward on the screen along a Bèzier curve, it decelerates until it gets to the top (at which point it momentarily stops, or has 0 speed or whatever), and then it starts to accelerate as it travels back down the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you could actually chain two Interpolators.  The first would be a `DecelerateInterpolator` from time 0 to time 1, then start an `AccelerateInterpolator` at time 1 to time 2. Basically split the time in half.

Comment: Yeah, so I thought about this. The problem is that the interpolators expect the range to go from 0-1. So, I'd need to map from the input value in the range 0-0.5 (for the decelerate interpolator), and then back again after running it through the decelerateinterpolator. It seems really complicated. I guess I was hoping there was a formula that would allow me to implement it directly.

Comment: Or, better yet, an already-implemented version. This seems to be "baked-in" to iOS.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Android API 21 or greater you can use [PathInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/PathInterpolator) with a cubic Bezier curve:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    TimeInterpolator lInter = new PathInterpolator(0.0f, 0.97f, 1.0f, 0.03f);
    animation.setInterpolator(lInter);
}
```

And here's a great website for calculating your desired [bezier curve values](http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,.97,1,.03):

Answer (score 3):

Try to use my custom Interpolator. And you're welcome :)

```
mAnimation.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float pInput) {
        System.out.println("input " + pInput);
        // (1-(1-(x*2))^3)/2
        return (float) (1 - Math.pow(1 - (2 * pInput), 3)) / 2;
    }
});
```